# Java , issue with main method

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have the following main method and a class called Bankkonto, When I create a new object in main method and then try to print it using getKonto , it does not appear, Please find my two classes below.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bankkonto a = new Bankkonto("Sohail", 5000);
        Bankkonto b = new Bankkonto("Chaudhry", 5500);

        System.out.print("Bankkonto är " + a.getNummer());
        System.out.print("Bankkonto är " + a.getSaldo());

        System.out.print("Bankkonto är " + b.getNummer());
        System.out.print("Bankkonto är " + b.getSaldo());

        a.insättning(500);
        b.uttag(500);

        System.out.print("Bankkonto är " + a.getSaldo());
        System.out.print("Bankkonto är " + b.getSaldo());   
    }
}

public class Bankkonto {

    private String nummer;
    private int saldo;
    private int belopp;


    public Bankkonto (String n, int s){
        n=nummer;
        s=saldo;

    }

    public String getNummer()
    {
        return nummer;

    }
    public int getSaldo()
    {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setNummer(String n)
    {
      nummer =n;
    }


    public void setSaldo(int s)
    {
      saldo =s;
    }

    public void insättning (int belopp){

        saldo = saldo + belopp;
    }

    public void uttag (int belopp){

        saldo = saldo- belopp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not appear"? What *does* appear?

Answer (score 8):

Assignment in `constructor` is inverse of what it should be. Assign the parameters to your local variables, not assign local variables to those parameters.

```
public Bankkonto (String n, int s){
    n=nummer; // wrong
    s=saldo;  // wrong
    }
```

Should be

```
public Bankkonto (String n, int s){
    nummer=n; 
    saldo=s;  
    }
```

Comment: solved it thank you... been staring at the problem for hours